# Spring Security & JSR-303: Entity validation on Filter level

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, hibernate-validator

I'm working on a `REST-service` with `Spring 4`. I want to validate an entity inside a filter chain. I can't use standard `@Validate` annotation inside `@Controller`, because required URI for a request is specified just on the filter level (I extended UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter for a further customization).

Please give me advice how to validate such entity inside a filter:

```
public class UserEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

as a result I want to be able to retrieve errors from a binder.

Thanks

Comment: Could you inject a Validator into your filter?  I think the class that performs all the "magic" behind the scenes is `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the issue via declaration of `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` in a `@Configuration` class, and then used it at filter level.

```
...
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
...
DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(entityWhichNeedToBeValidated);
binder.setValidator(validator);
binder.validate();
BindingResult result = binder.getBindingResult();
...
```

After this I have a full information about the validated fields and complete program flow as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this give you a some hint for implement rest call with spring validation. http://spring.io/blog/2012/08/29/integrating-spring-mvc-with-jquery-for-validation-rules